# Google Sheets Index Sidebar of all tabs - add search functionality

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

After some searching I found this code to get a sidebar of all tabs (workbooks) in Google Sheets as a hyperlink. I am looking to add two functionalities to this, if its possible

1. Search function - a search box on sidebar to look up tabs more easily
2. Same tab - open the clicked hyperlinked tab in the same browser tab instead of opening in a new window.

Here's the code so far:

```
    function onOpen() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
          .createMenu('Sidebar Menu')
          .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
          .addToUi();
    }
    
    function showSidebar() {
      var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sidebar.html')
          .evaluate()
          .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
          .setTitle('Index Sidebar');
      
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
    }
        
    function getSheetNames() {
      
      // Get all the different sheet IDs
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheets = ss.getSheets();
      
      return sheetNamesIds(sheets);
    }
        
    // function to create array of sheet names and sheet ids
    function sheetNamesIds(sheets) {
      
      var indexOfSheets = [];
      
      // create array of sheet names and sheet gids
      sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
        indexOfSheets.push([sheet.getSheetName(),sheet.getSheetId()]);
       
      });
      
      //Logger.log(indexOfSheets);
      return indexOfSheets; 
    }
```

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>Index of all sheets in this workbook:</h1>
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

<ol>
<?!= getSheetNames().map(function(d) {
    return "<li><a href='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1234/edit#gid=" + d[1] + "' target='_blank'>" + d[0] + "</a></li>";
    }).join(''); ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `1. Search function - a search box on sidebar to look up tabs more easily. 2. Same tab - open the clicked hyperlinked tab in the same browser tab instead of opening in a new window.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Proposed Solution

You should be able to replace the code you posted with what is below and have it work. First copy and paste it into the two files and then run it from the Sheet, not from the Script Editor.

[image]

### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>Index of all sheets in this workbook:</h1>
<script>

function removeElement(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

function buildList(text) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).returnListItems(text)
}

function onSuccess(result) {
    var element = document.createElement("ol")
    element.innerHTML = result
    var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar")
    sidebar.appendChild(element)
}

function getTextAndSearch() {
    var text = document.getElementById("text-search").value
    removeElement("ol")
    buildList(text)
}


</script>
<sidebar id="sidebar">
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="text-search" />
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="getTextAndSearch()" />

    <ol id="ol">
       <?!=
        returnListItems()
       ?>
    </ol>
</sidebar>
```

### JS

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Sidebar Menu')
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sidebar.html')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('Index Sidebar');
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function getSheetNames() {
  
  // Get all the different sheet IDs
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  return sheetNamesIds(sheets);
}

// function to create array of sheet names and sheet ids
function sheetNamesIds(sheets) {
  
  var indexOfSheets = [];
  
  // create array of sheet names and sheet gids
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    indexOfSheets.push([sheet.getSheetName(),sheet.getSheetId()]);
    
  });
  
  //Logger.log(indexOfSheets);
  return indexOfSheets; 
}

// function to return a button with onclick attribute for each sheet that matches

function returnListItems(text) {
  
    var sheetNames = getSheetNames()
    
    // Checking if there is a search term
    if (text) {
      sheetNames = sheetNames.filter(n => n[0].includes(text))
    }
    
    var htmlString = sheetNames.map(function(d) {
        var string = `
        <li> 
          <input
           type="button"
           value="${d[0]}"
           onclick=\"google.script.run.setActiveByName('${d[0]}')\"/>
        </li>
        `
        return string }).join(' ')
    
    return htmlString
}

// Utility function to set Active sheet by name.
function setActiveByName(name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name)
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss)
}
```

You may need to create a dummy function in the script editor: `function init(){}` and run it just to grant the permissions the script needs, though this should happen when you run the script from the menu.

### Explanation

#### Bringing sheets into focus - `setActiveSheet`

<sup>*This is relatively simple so I have included it in the answer, though technically is a **second question**. In future ensure to only ask **one question** per post, it keeps things tidier on the site and easier for future users to search for answers. Thank you*</sup>

This involves using [`setActiveSheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setactivesheetsheet) for which I made the utility function `setActiveByName`.

To insert this function into each link, I wrote the function `returnListItems`, that  generates and returns the HTML for each button to call the `setActiveByName` when clicked. Writing it as a second function was not strictly necessary, but it made things clearer, especially since it would make the main question a lot easier.

#### Search function

What seemed relatively simple when I started quickly got quite complicated. It involved breaking up some of the code into its component functionality, to make it easier to work with. Yet the biggest challenge is properly setting up the server side code (Apps Script editor) and the client side code (contained in the HTML).

Once the Sidebar is loaded, I found that any further manipulation of the sidebar HTML needed to be done client side, hence the functions in the HTML. The solution lay in the ["Client-to-Server Communication"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers) article in the docs.

The search button is pressed, then the client side script gets the text in the Search input box, passes it to the `buildList` function, also client side, which in turn calls:

`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).returnListItems([SEARCH_TERM])`

This is a asynchronous function that goes server side. The "Success Handler" is the call back function that runs when the list items are returned. `onSuccess` simply updates the HTML in the sidebar. I modified the `returnListItems` function to be able to accept a search term, so when it runs the first time, it runs without any arguments so all sheets are returned. When called by the client side function, it runs with a text. If the sheet name contains the search term, it is listed.

#### References

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html)
- [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)
- [Client-Server Communications](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)
- [JS includes (for search)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response and explanation. I am, however, getting  _Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 14, file "code")_ error. Could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: You get this error because you are calling the function from the script editor and not the menu item. Since the script is run from the script editor, there is no appropriate "UI" object to get. You will have to run any function in the script editor to be able to give all the permissions though, so you could consider making a blank function `function init(){}` and run that to get the permissions, then open the sidebar from the custom menu in the sheet. I will update my answer to be a bit clearer in this respect.

Comment: I added a short video to demonstrate the function in action and put in some more instructions about setup.

Comment: sorry if am being a pain but now am getting error:

_TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheets' of null (line 21, file "code"_
thanks for the gifs, so jealous  why is it not working for me.. 

Comment: When you made your spreadsheet, did you open the script editor from the menu of the spreadsheet? Or is it a "separate" script? See more about that [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) - if you have a standalone script, then instead of  `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` on line 21, I think you would need to use `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[SS_ID]");` - [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)

Comment: You would also need to change this near the end of the script `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name)` to  `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[ID]").getSheetByName(name)` - you need to replace the `[ID]` with the spreadsheet ID

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you
          This is working now!!!

     I found this line somewhere that allows
     `if(sheet.isSheetHidden()!= true)` to show only non-hidden sheets in the Index
    There's one small thing, the Index only shows the first word of the sheet name, can this be fixed? The word after space does not show.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. I have updated the script to deal with spaces, it was a simple fix! In `returnListItems` instead of the line `value=${d[0]}` it is now `value="${d[0]}"`

Comment: Perfect! the updated script works great!! it's amazing how you know all this!!!

Comment: Quite impressive! Is this still a valid answer? Because I click on the buttons and nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Ian for your solution above.  Works well!  After some trial and error, I was able to tweak it to ensure hidden sheets aren't included.  Below is the updated code for anyone else interested:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Sidebar Menu')
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar.html')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('Index Sidebar');
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}


function getSheetNames() {
  
  // Get all the different sheet IDs
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(s => !s.isSheetHidden());
  
  return sheetNamesIds(sheets);
}


// function to create array of sheet names and sheet ids
function sheetNamesIds(sheets) {
  
  var indexOfSheets = [];

  // create array of sheet names and sheet gids
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
  
    indexOfSheets.push([sheet.getSheetName(),sheet.getSheetId()]);
        
  });

  
  //Logger.log(indexOfSheets);
  return indexOfSheets; 
}


// function to return a button with onclick attribute for each sheet that matches
function returnListItems(text) {
  
    var sheetNames = getSheetNames()
    
    // Checking if there is a search term
    if (text) {
      sheetNames = sheetNames.filter(n => n[0].includes(text))
    }
    
    var htmlString = sheetNames.map(function(d) {
        var string = `
        <li> 
          <input
           type="button"
           value="${d[0]}"
           onclick=\"google.script.run.setActiveByName('${d[0]}')\"/>
        </li>
        `
        return string }).join(' ')
    
    return htmlString
}



// Utility function to set Active sheet by name.
function setActiveByName(name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name)
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss)
}
```