# I've run a script for Google Sheets sidebar that is supposed to not show hidden tabs but they still show. Asking the community how to fix this

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a question about:  [Google Sheets Index Sidebar of all tabs - add search functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247205/google-sheets-index-sidebar-of-all-tabs-add-search-functionality/71519188#71519188)

The last answer in the above includes the code below and this note:  "After some trial and error, I was able to tweak it to ensure hidden sheets aren't included."

When I run the code, my sidebar still shows hidden tabs.  Am not a programmer so I would respectfully ask that answers take this into consideration.  Thank you.  Sidebar is a terrific addition; really appreciate the author & contributors.  Here is the code:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Sidebar Menu')
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar.html')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('Index Sidebar');
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}


function getSheetNames() {
  
  // Get all the different sheet IDs
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(s => !s.isSheetHidden());
  
  return sheetNamesIds(sheets);
}


// function to create array of sheet names and sheet ids
function sheetNamesIds(sheets) {
  
  var indexOfSheets = [];

  // create array of sheet names and sheet gids
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
  
    indexOfSheets.push([sheet.getSheetName(),sheet.getSheetId()]);
        
  });

  
  //Logger.log(indexOfSheets);
  return indexOfSheets; 
}


// function to return a button with onclick attribute for each sheet that matches
function returnListItems(text) {
  
    var sheetNames = getSheetNames()
    
    // Checking if there is a search term
    if (text) {
      sheetNames = sheetNames.filter(n => n[0].includes(text))
    }
    
    var htmlString = sheetNames.map(function(d) {
        var string = `
        <li> 
          <input
           type="button"
           value="${d[0]}"
           onclick=\"google.script.run.setActiveByName('${d[0]}')\"/>
        </li>
        `
        return string }).join(' ')
    
    return htmlString
}



// Utility function to set Active sheet by name.
function setActiveByName(name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name)
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss)
}
```

The above is all of the code I'm aware of other than the HTML and JS below.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>Index of all sheets in this workbook:</h1>
<script>

function removeElement(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

function buildList(text) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).returnListItems(text)
}

function onSuccess(result) {
    var element = document.createElement("ol")
    element.innerHTML = result
    var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar")
    sidebar.appendChild(element)
}

function getTextAndSearch() {
    var text = document.getElementById("text-search").value
    removeElement("ol")
    buildList(text)
}


</script>
<sidebar id="sidebar">
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="text-search" />
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="getTextAndSearch()" />

    <ol id="ol">
       <?!=
        returnListItems()
       ?>
    </ol>
</sidebar>
JS
```

JS

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Sidebar Menu')
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sidebar.html')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('Index Sidebar');
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function getSheetNames() {
  
  // Get all the different sheet IDs
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  return sheetNamesIds(sheets);
}

// function to create array of sheet names and sheet ids
function sheetNamesIds(sheets) {
  
  var indexOfSheets = [];
  
  // create array of sheet names and sheet gids
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    indexOfSheets.push([sheet.getSheetName(),sheet.getSheetId()]);
    
  });
  
  //Logger.log(indexOfSheets);
  return indexOfSheets; 
}

// function to return a button with onclick attribute for each sheet that matches

function returnListItems(text) {
  
    var sheetNames = getSheetNames()
    
    // Checking if there is a search term
    if (text) {
      sheetNames = sheetNames.filter(n => n[0].includes(text))
    }
    
    var htmlString = sheetNames.map(function(d) {
        var string = `
        <li> 
          <input
           type="button"
           value="${d[0]}"
           onclick=\"google.script.run.setActiveByName('${d[0]}')\"/>
        </li>
        `
        return string }).join(' ')
    
    return htmlString
}

// Utility function to set Active sheet by name.
function setActiveByName(name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name)
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss)
}
```

Hopefullly I've included everything needed.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the whole script for correctly replicating `When I run the code, my sidebar still shows hidden tabs.`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've updated the post.